# Add multiple piecewise_nd blocks to pyomo model

Tags: pyomo

I am trying to include a multivariate non-linear function in the scheduling problem from [this tutorial](https://jckantor.github.io/ND-Pyomo-Cookbook/notebooks/04.03-Job-Shop-Scheduling.html#application-to-the-scheduling-of-batch-processes). Basically, this function calculates a value based on the starting and idle times of the job at a given machine. It is a smooth concave function, no discontinuities.

I am using the 'piecewise_nd' function for that. For each pair (job, machine), I need to assign a different piecewise_nd block to a concrete model instance. The scheduling model code is identical to the tutorial and this is done in the piece of code below, which fails on "model.add_component(f'piecewise_{j}_{m}', piecewise)" with the message:  `AttributeError: 'piecewise_nd_cc' object has no attribute 'valid_model_component'`.

Does anyone know how to get around this, or have a better approach to add multiple n-dimensional piecewise models in a loop? Ideally, I wanted to achieve the same functionality available for the [Piecewise object](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/pyomo/core/base/piecewise.py), which can be created with an index set as a parameter.

```py
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.core.kernel.piecewise_library.transforms_nd import piecewise_nd
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

# the linearization auxiliary variable
model.cost = pyo.Var(model.TASKS, bounds=(0, None))
# apply the linearization
triangulation = Delaunay(points) # points: any 2-d array
values = f(*triangulation.points.T)
for j,m in model.TASKS:
   var_list = [model.start[j,m], model.idle[j,m]]
   piecewise = piecewise_nd(triangulation,        
                             values=values,    
                             input=var_list,
                             output=model.cost[j,m],
                             bound='eq',
                             repn='cc')
   # add the piecewise_nd block to the model
   model.add_component(f'piecewise_{j}_{m}', piecewise)
# set the objective
model.objective = pyo.Objective(expr = sum([model.cost[j,m] for j,m in model.TASKS]), sense = pyo.minimize)
```

I tried the approach from [this question](https://groups.google.com/g/pyomo-forum/c/z3PoIVHvvJM/m/hJjUFRb1CgAJ), but the `add_component` function is not working properly with the `piecewise_nd` object, throwing the error above.

**EDIT**

The full code is available in [this notebook](https://github.com/vicrsp/pyomo-piecewise-nd/blob/main/Pyomo%20piecewise_nd.ipynb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, it would be helpful to post the entire error stack trace and not just the message.  It is also challenging to debug your model / verify a solution, as you have not provided a complete example.

That said, the kernel library is an experimental / development library and is not 100% compatible with the rest of Pyomo.  In particular, it looks like kernel modeling objects do not all implement the full Component API and cause an error in `add_component()`.  Based on the kernel piecewise unit tests, I think you can work around the problem by using:

```py
setattr(model, f'piecewise_{j}_{m}', piecewise)
```

instead of

```py
model.add_component(f'piecewise_{j}_{m}', piecewise)
```

Finally, I should point out that there is active development work on a new multivariate piecewise capability (in `pyomo.contrib.piecewise`) that aims to be 100% compatible with the core Pyomo AML.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the approach you suggested and it now adds the piecewise functions. However, the piecewise functions are not being applied, and all elements in the `cost` variable remain at the specified lower bound. I believe it is related to this feature being still experimental, as you pointed out. By the way, I edited the answer including a notebook where everyone can reproduce the issue, I hope it helps.

Comment: From your example, it looks like you are mixing kernel with the normal AML classes.  I am pretty sure that is not supported.  You might try using the `pyomo.contrib.piecewise` multivariate piecewise components.  Unfortunately it is still under development and there is no documentation, but you might be able to get started by looking at the tests in `pyomo/contrib/piecewise/tests`